# ¿Como agregar una linea promedio a una grafica en chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

Acá un ejemplo de una gráfica que realizo:

```js
var data_labels = ['Tue Jul 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Wed Jul 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Thu Jul 06 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Fri Jul 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sat Jul 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sun Jul 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Mon Jul 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Tue Jul 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Wed Jul 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Thu Jul 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Fri Jul 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sat Jul 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sun Jul 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Mon Jul 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Tue Jul 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Wed Jul 19 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Thu Jul 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Fri Jul 21 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sat Jul 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sun Jul 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)'];

var data_data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: data_labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: '# de Equipos con Paradas de Mantenimiento',
                data: data_data,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188,1)'
            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
                    return {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188,1)'
                    }
                },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return '#: '+tooltipItem.yLabel;
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'DD MMM YYYY'
                    },
                    tooltipFormat: 'DD [de] MMM [de] YYYY', 
                },
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    //maxRotation: 50, // angle in degrees
                },
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    maxRotation: 0, // angle in degrees
                    stepSize: 1
                },
            }]
        },
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0,
            }
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 500, // general animation time
        },
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 500, // duration of animations when hovering an item
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 500, // animation duration after a resize
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/es.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 180px; width: 633px;" height="180" width="633"></canvas>
```

Yo quisiera agregar una linea promedio como la siguiente:

[image: gráfica]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añadí un poco de funcionalidad a tu gráfica, no se si es exactamente lo que buscas, pero mas o menos combinando gráficas y haciendo algunos cálculos en base a promedio de lapsos de datos.

Revisado a ver si lo puedes utilizar:

```js
var data_labels = ['Tue Jul 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Wed Jul 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Thu Jul 06 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Fri Jul 07 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sat Jul 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sun Jul 09 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Mon Jul 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Tue Jul 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Wed Jul 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Thu Jul 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Fri Jul 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sat Jul 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sun Jul 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Mon Jul 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Tue Jul 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Wed Jul 19 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Thu Jul 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Fri Jul 21 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sat Jul 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)', 'Sun Jul 23 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Hora estándar oeste, Sudamérica)'];

var data_data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1];

var data_promedio = [];// [0, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1];

var sum = 0 ;
var len = data_data.length;
var lapso = 5;//Moviendo este lapso se mueve la linea, se va sacando el promedio entre ese lapso de puntos
var promedios = []
var sumLapso =0;
var countLapso = 0;
$.each(data_data, function(i,v){
  countLapso = countLapso + 1;
  if(i == 0 || i== (data_data.length -1)){
    data_promedio.push(v);
  }else{
    data_promedio.push(null);
  }
  if(i%lapso == 0){
    promedios.push(sumLapso/(countLapso ==0 ? 1 : countLapso));
    countLapso = 0;
    sumLapso = 0;
    sumLapso = v;
    //sum1 =sum1 + v;
    //count1 = count1 + 1;
  }else{  
    sumLapso = sumLapso + v;
    //sum2 =sum2 + v;
    //count2 = count2 + 1;
  }
  //console.log(v);
  sum = sum + v;
});

$.each(promedios, function(i,v){
  console.log(v);
  if(i == 0 || i== (promedios.length -1)){
    data_promedio[i] = v;
  }else{
    data_promedio[i+lapso] = v;
  }
});

//console.log(sum + ' ' + sum1 + ' ' + sum2);
//console.log(len + ' ' + count1 + ' ' + count2);
/*
var prom = sum / data_data.length;

data_promedio[0] = prom-1;
data_promedio[data_data.length -1] = prom;
console.log(prom);
*/
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: data_labels,
        datasets: [ {
                label: 'Promedio',
                data: data_promedio,
                type: 'line',
                lineTension: .6,
                pointRadius: 0,
                fill: false,
                spanGaps: true,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            },
            {
                label: '# de Equipos con Paradas de Mantenimiento',
                data: data_data,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188,1)'
            }
        ]
    }
    ,
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
                    return {
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.2)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(60, 141, 188,1)'
                    }
                },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return '#: '+tooltipItem.yLabel;
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'DD MMM YYYY'
                    },
                    tooltipFormat: 'DD [de] MMM [de] YYYY', 
                },
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    //maxRotation: 50, // angle in degrees
                },
            }]
            /*,//Comente esta parte porque hace que la linea de promedio aparezca mas arriba
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 10,
                    maxRotation: 0, // angle in degrees
                    stepSize: 1
                },
            }]*/
        }
        ,
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0,
            }
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 500, // general animation time
        },
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 500, // duration of animations when hovering an item
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 500, // animation duration after a resize
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/es.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 180px; width: 633px;" height="180" width="633"></canvas>
```

Comment: gracias, justo lo que necesito :D

Comment: Me da gusto, Que bien :)